# Close result set in loop using Java

Tags: java, jdbc

This question should be simple and it may annoy , but still I got this doubt about closing of Result Set using Java. It should be done for each statement or result set should be closed only in final?

```
       try {
        Class.forName(<driver class>);                
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "IP", 
            "username",
            "password");
        for(String dealId : items) {
            String sql= "SQL Query";
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                count += rs.getInt("total");                    
            }
            // Result should be closed here as the statement got executed?
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        if(items.size() == count) {
            dealsBelongToTheParty = true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        rs.close(); // Or this is right?
        preparedStatement.close();
        if(!con.isClosed())
            con.close();
    }
```

Comment: best done in finally block

Comment: even better would be to use try-with-resource

Comment: You seem to be creating a new result set in each iteration of your `for` loop. In that case, the logical thing would be to close each one in the for loop, instead of just closing whichever one is left at the end.

Comment: Cramming multiple close statements in one finally block is a really bad idea. You'll cause a connection leak.

Comment: You are leaking both ResultSets and PreparedStatements. You should close both every time around the loop. Fortunately provided you are using a fully compliant JDBC driver they will all get closed when you close the statement. But that may not be soon enough for all purposes.

Comment: 1) First of all put preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql); outside the loop. 2) close ResultSet each time: rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); creates a new ResultSet each time, the previous resutl set remains unclosed

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev it is assumed that the loop var `dealId` is used in the query...

Comment: @ Sharon Ben Asher yes, but this is supposed to be parameter of parameterized SQL

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev this is another issue of optimizing the sql query.  it will work just fine if the variable is embedded in the sql string

Comment: @EJP, Can you provide the exact solution where there will be no leakages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use Java 7 try-with-resources
(the code below assumes that the loop var `dealId` is used in the query)

```
Class.forName(<driver class>);                
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "IP", "username", "password")) {
    for(String dealId : items) {
        String sql= "SQL Query with " + dealId;
        // resources are opened by order 
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
             ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            while(rs.next()) {
                count += rs.getInt("total");                    
            }
        } // resources are implicitly closed in reverse order of open
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(count);
if(items.size() == count) {
    dealsBelongToTheParty = true;
}
```

Comment: ResultSet is also AutoCloseable

Comment: ...and is also inside try-with-resources...

Comment: There won't be any memory leakages in this case? and where did you close the statement, resultset & connection? I was asking about closing the result set

Comment: It should be done in the finally or right after try block? Im worrying about memory leakage.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, please add the closing statements of resources. After which line you want to close. You cannot close it after try, because rs object is defined inside try block. Please let me know

Comment: @Aliy, in try-with-resouces there is no explicit close.  it is added by the compiler at the closing bracket of the try block

Comment: So, there will not be any memory leakages in your code. Am I right?

Comment: no leakage of DB resources

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

"A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results."

So, you shouldn't worry about closing ResultSet.

Comment: then why is `ResultSet` implements `AutoCloseable`?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, because it can be closed exclicitly.

Comment: The OP is creating a new statement in every iteration of the `for` loop. So the cited doc doesn't cover his case.